# Multiple different composer autoloaders in plugins, but only one autoloader is really working

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, autoloader

I'm working on plugin that uses autoloader from composer. But for some reason, when I'm creating new object, PHP loads different autoloader from different plugin, and all my work is not accessible. So here is *composer.json*:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CustomizableProduct\\": "inc"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "lib"
    }
}
```

That's how I'm trying to load base plugin class in *my_plugin.php* file:

```php
define('MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

add_action('init', function () {
    require_once MY_PLUGIN_PATH . "/lib/autoload.php";

    new \CustomizableProduct\CustomizableProduct();
});
```

Every time PHP shows me error that class was not found. **BUT** when I'm dumping autoload with `optimize-autoloader` param, suddenly it works great. 
Ok, I can live with that optimized autoloader, but I need to load Woocommerce classes to create custom product type. Unfortunately, changing *composer.json* to

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CustomizableProduct\\": "inc",
            "Woocommerce\\": "../woocommerce"
        }
    },
```

or with simpler, global version

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CustomizableProduct\\": "inc",
            "\\": "../"
        }
    },
```

not working, even with dumping autoloader with optimization param.

I have no idea what to do. Am I doing something wrong? I'm thinking about setting my own autoloader, or eventually just to create file only with *include_once*, including all my classes.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same classes in both plugins? E.g. trying to get `Woocommerce\` classes in both? That won't work. The first autoloader to find the class will return it, the other will never be hit. Composer is a poor fit for Wordpress, because of Wordpress "architecture".

Comment: Thank you, good to know. Maybe that's why I'm getting wrong autoloader object. What alternatives do you propose?